# How to count all users in database with some specific attribute in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: Reseller Table]

[image: Users table]

I have a table for Reseller and Users. Now Each reseller has his own users. and each user is mapped to that reseller by a field called key. So each user will have a field called key in which the key of reseller would be saved.

Now i have a filed called allocation block. This is the maximum no of users a reseller can have. Now for eg a reseller has allocation block of 100 users, but initially inserts only 10 users. So i want to print the remaining users he is allowed to add. So allocation block-intitals_users. that would be 100-10 so on reseller login i want to show how much user he can add.

Please help me to generate a query to count the remaining users he can avail.

Comment: Can you please share the table names, along with the table design for having a look at?

Comment: @MaK The table names are reseller and users. and have added the structure of table

Comment: i went though CI user guide and found out that $this->db->having('user_id = 45');  might help in this case but dont know how do i use it here

Comment: CI only provides an abstraction of SQL, nothing more, nothing less. You're not looking for a CI specific feature. There is none. At least none that I know of. You should use good ol' SQL to `SELECT COUNT(users) WHERE key = resellerKey`, and subtract it from the resellers' allocation block.

Comment: @ROAL  how to pass the key here? can you please post an answer with a query

Comment: @MaK can you please see the updated question

Comment: Well here is what I can think of, have a subquery which'll fetch you the count of user the reseller has right now, on the top of it have the query which'll return you the `maxPossibleUser` that the reseller can add, subtract it, now you have your magic number. Lemme know if you need any help on writing the query.

Comment: @MaK i just do'nt know how to write this query :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it in steps: Let's say we're working with reseller `Zalak` in your table, which has an allocation_block size of `500` and an key of `Zalak-+76-6-500-1` and an id of `6`

#### Find the Amount of Users belonging to a Reseller

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CurrentUserTotal FROM Users WHERE key = 'Zalak-+76-6-500-1';
```

#### Find the allocation_block value of that reseller

```
SELECT allocation_block AS AllowedUserTotal FROM Resellers WHERE id '6';
```

#### Put them together to get both at once

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(u.*) AS CurrentUserTotal, 
    r.allocation_block AS AllowedUserTotal 
FROM Users u 
JOIN Resellers r 
    ON (u.key = r.key) 
WHERE r.id = '6';
```

#### Do the math to get the value you're after

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(u.*) AS CurrentUserTotal, 
    r.allocation_block AS AllowedUserTotal,
    SUM(AllowedUserTotal - CurrentUserTotal) AS RemainingUserTotal
FROM Users u 
JOIN Resellers r 
    ON (u.key = r.key) 
WHERE r.id = '6';
```

#### Put it all together

Using CI, you can now just do this:

```
public function getRemainingAllowedUsers( $reseller_id ) {

    $SQL = "
        SELECT 
            COUNT(u.*) AS CurrentUserTotal, 
            r.allocation_block AS AllowedUserTotal,
            SUM(AllowedUserTotal - CurrentUserTotal) AS RemainingUserTotal
        FROM Users u 
        JOIN Resellers r 
            ON (u.key = r.key) 
        WHERE r.id = '" . $reseller_id . "';
    ";
    $query = $this->db->query($SQL);
    $result = $query->row();

    $current_users   = $result->CurrentUserTotal;
    $allowed_users   = $result->AllowedUserTotal;
    $remaining_users = $result->RemainingUserTotal;

}
```